# Develop OAF Pages without an EBS Instance

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, oracle-ebs, application-framework

Is it possible to Develop OAF Pages via JDeveloper without an EBS Instance?
I was hoping to connect it to just a local Oracle 11g Database.

Reason i'm asking is whenever I run the page from JDeveloper, it takes such a long time to load a simple page (about 5 - 10 Mins).
I'm connecting to a remote EBS Instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:
[Can I develop OAF pages (extension to EBS R12) without having an EBS instance in my computer?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3718997?start=15&tstart=0)

As per user aJohny (i rephrased some of this words):

> You need to have access to an E-Business Suite Instance. Just having an Oracle Database is not good enough. It all depends of what (level of) customization you want to do and what objects are involved. Worst case, if System Administrators/DBAs don't want to give access and you want to develop the pages from Jdeveloper, you need to create dummy tables in your database and use that to develop. But you will not be able to test. You can just develop, you need to deploy this into the server to test.

I also realized that during the OA Page Creation, we are supplying the `FND_USER` Logins and the Responsibility Assigned to the said user, which further proves we need a working EBS instance to develop OAF pages.